# run django-cms at the beginning

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I do the following steps to run django-cms at the beginig

first I install virtualenv and active it then I install djangocms-installer by pip.. 
when I want to run `djangocms -f -p . mysite` I got this erorr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 15, in execute
config_data = config.parse(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djangocms_installer/config/__init__.py", line 42, in parse
required=False, default=get_localzone(),
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 122, in get_localzone
_cache_tz = _get_localzone()
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 114, in _get_localzone
return pytz.tzfile.build_tzinfo('local', tzfile)
  File "/home/sahar/cms/2/sahar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pytz/tzfile.py", line 30, in build_tzinfo
typecnt, charcnt) =  unpack(head_fmt, fp.read(head_size))
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 44
```

what is wrong with my steps?
I follow these steps from [docs.django-cms](http://django-cms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

Django CMS doesnt supports python 3.5

```
django CMS requires Django version 1.6.9 or later, 1.7 or 1.8, and Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 or 3.4.
```